# Dynamically resizing image with JS onload event is delayed in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I want to resize a number of images of varying size to 50% of their native size using the following JS:

onload="this.width>>=1;this.onload=null;

This works well in most browsers, except in Firefox whereby it appears to load in full size first before resizing after approximately a second.

What can I do to ensure that the image is resized as soon as the user sees the image?

Answer (score 0):

If the native size of the images cannot be foreknown, then I would add some more attributes to my images. One way is this:

```
<img onload="this.width>>=1;this.onload=null;this.style.visibility='visible'" style="visibility:hidden">
```

You can play around with different css properties, like `display:none` or `width:0` until Firefox does what you intend.

Another approach is to use background image instead. But I need more information about your situation to provide an answer with background-image property

Comment: Thanks for your response. The crucial point here is that we do not know the native size of each image, hence the need for a more dynamic solution (for high-resolution displays, essentially). 

The images appear within a data table and therefore have a confined space to conform to. I had thought about using background-image, but I couldn't think how I'd get the size of the element itself to be correct.